# Trying to commit to GitHub using powershell results in error "fatal: unable to access 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem"

Tags: git, powershell, github, windows-7, github-for-windows

I want to run a powershell script to push to git automatically every so often.

I have GitHub installed for windows. If I run "Git Shell", a powershell shell opens but it has the `git` function installed and starts in `C:\Users\crclayton\Desktop\GitHub>` not in `H:\>`

If I try to use `git` in a normal PowerShell, it tells me git isn't recognized as a function. However, if I load the script `C:\Users\crclayton\AppData\Local\GitHub\shell.ps1` in the normal powershell, I can use `git`, but when I navigate to the folder and try to `add` or `commit` or `push`, I get the error:

> git.exe : fatal: unable to access
>
> 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\mypath../.config/git/config': Invalid argument At
>
> C:\Users\crclayton\Desktop\autogit.ps1:7 char:4
>
> - git <<<<  add *
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (fatal: unable t...nvalid argument:     String) [], RemoteException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

This is my code:

```
#(Resolve-Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\GitHub\shell.ps1") # tried this, doesn't work
C:\Users\crclayton\AppData\Local\GitHub\shell.ps1

$msg = Read-Host "Enter commit msg"

cd "C:\Users\crclayton\project\"
git add *
git commit -a -m $msg
git push origin master
```

Can anyone see what's wrong or suggest an alternative? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use git commands inside a powershell script make sure you have a record in the environment variable 'Path' with the actual path to the git. 
In my case it looks as shown on the attached picture!:

[image: Path environment variable]

Anyway, this setting was automatically added when I installed Git Extensions. If you don't use extensions just add this line to the 'Path' variable eather manually or from powershell script.

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you! This worked, but only after I found `git.exe` buried away in the following folder: `C:\Users\crclayton\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\bin`.

Answer (score 1):

Github for windows uses `posh-git` so you may want to confirm that you are **[following the manual install](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#installing-manual)** to be used by powershell.

> Verify execution of scripts is allowed with `Get-ExecutionPolicy` (should be `RemoteSigned` or `Unrestricted`). If scripts are not enabled, run PowerShell as Administrator and call `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Confirm`.